# Return only matched documents with regexFind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate query which correctly "marks" the matched documents but returns all the documents on the collection. How do I return only the matched documents?

Here's my query:

```
db.trainers.aggregate([
                { $addFields: { returnObject: { $regexFind: { input: "$username", regex: /master/ } } } },
]);

// 1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fe1c555607a0d05492dc481"),
    "email": "PraXXXes0@gmail.com",
    "username": "816XXX063",
    "created": ISODate("2020-12-22T10:07:17.172Z"),
    "returnObject": null,
}

// 2
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fe046caddfee639193a4880"),
    "email": "HobbiXXXXious@gmail.com ",
    "username": "PoXXXXmaster75785",
    "created": ISODate("2020-12-21T06:55:06.262Z"),
    "returnObject": {
        "match": "master",
        "idx": NumberInt("4"),
        "captures": [ ]
    },
}
```

I do not want those returnObject nulls...

Thanks

Comment: you just need to put only match stage with $regex `{ $match: { username: { $regex: 
 "master" } } }`

Comment: This return no document

Comment: check this working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5yjXYAH6WdM)

Comment: yes, sorry. Had a skip:1 on next stage